# Django Detailview display properties of parent

Tags: python, django, detailview

I'm trying to use DetailView. I don't have a deep understanding of it.

What I'm trying to do is display the properties of an object from the pk. That is, I'm at, say, /notendur/34, and I want to display information about the object with pk=34.

I'm trying to make sense of this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/

But I can't make sense of it. Perhaps one of you can help me understand? I'm looking at the second block of code in that link, not the first one.

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %}
{{ "placeholder" }}
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

I'm looking to use the HTML to fetch the pk from /notendur/34 for example.

Comment: This is not the relevant question. What have you tried? What it is which you don't understand or having issues?

Comment: I don't understand how I can fetch an object based on the pk in /notendur/34. I haven't tried anything, because I don't know of any way. I added some code to the OP.

Comment: The detail view automatically pass object with pk 34 named as `object` in context. You can access that in template e.g. `{{ object.pk }}` or  `{{ object.some_property_name }}`

Answer (score 1):

The detail view automatically pass object with primary key `34` named as `object` in context. You can access that in template e.g. `{{ object.pk }}` or  `{{ object.some_property_name }}`

Answer (score 1):

First of all in your views you need to load the appropriate class:

```
from django.views.generic import (
    DetailView,
)
```

According to the Class Based View Inspector (keep a ref on this link):
http://ccbv.co.uk/

The DetailView has the following properties:

```
content_type = None
context_object_name = None
http_method_names = [u'get', u'post', u'put', u'patch', u'delete', u'head', u'options', u'trace']   View
model = None
pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'
queryset = None
response_class = <class 'django.template.response.TemplateResponse'>
slug_field = 'slug'
slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'
template_name = None
template_name_field = None
template_name_suffix = '_detail'
```

As you can see from the above, when the DetailView is called, it will check first for the existence of a pk or slug argument in the request,
this is done in your urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^view/(?P<slug>[\d]+)/$', MyTestDetailView.as_view(), name='myurl-name'),
    ...
)
```

By defining the slug parameter in the url, the DetailView knows which item you request details for (alternative you could use pk, but slug makes more friendly urls).
It then will fetch the model or the queryset (defined in your view) based on either the slug or pk field, this is performed in the def get_object(self, queryset=None) method.
After grabbing the model (if it fails it raises a 404 error) you can use the object within your template (specified under the template_name property) as:

```
{{ object }}
```

If you want to change the name of the template variable, you can assign a context_object_name property. A quick example is bellow:

```
from django.views.generic import (
    DetailView,
)

from myapp.models import (
    MyModel,
)

class MyTestDetailView(DetailView):
    """
    Set context object name to mytemplatevar
    """
    context_object_name = "mytemplatevar"
    """
    Define the model to use
    """
    model = MyModel
    """
    Define the template
    """
    template_name = "myapp/detail_view.html"
```

Appart from that you don't need anything else, in your template then you can access your object:

```
{{ mytemplatevar.something }}
```